# Info on Drupal.settings and #attached

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use Drupal.settings for the first time to pass variables from PHP to JavaScript. The documentation on the topic is sparse and I have a few issues.

Is it possible to use #attached to pass through the settings rather than `drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => $settings), 'setting');`? The reason I am asking is that I've been told that `#attached` is the "correct" way to add settings. ( I know it is also the correct way to add files also, but not sure if it works with settings variables.)

I'm using the following code, but I can't get it to load under the DOM objects and I am stuck.

```
(function ($) {
   Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
     attach: function(context, settings) {}
   };
});(jQuery);
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Please bear in mind that this is the first time I've set out to use Drupal.settings, so every detail is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks for the responses posted.

As mentioned in the original question, the issue was not how to load CSS & JS files using #attached, but how to pass variables through to Drupal.settings using #attached and not drupal_add_js().  There are best practice issues surrounding drupal_add_js with regard to caching and availability under the DOM.

After some research I have the solution. The following example uses #attached to load a JS file **AND** to pass PHP variables through by attaching them to the $page array (render array).

```
hook_page_alter() {

  $my_PHP_variable  // or array of variables

  $page['header']['#attached']['js'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/mymodule.js' => array(),
    array(
      // Pass PHP variables to Drupal.settings.
      'data' => array('myModuleVarSet' => $my_PHP_variable),
      'type' => 'setting',
   ),
);
}
```

So the reason I want to do this is that I want to pass variable states from PHP/Drupal to a jQuery file, such as booleans etc..  With the example above, I can now access that 'state' using:

```
var myVar = Drupal.settings.myModuleVarSet.my_PHP_variable;
```

This is all done without touching drupal_add_js();

Answer (score 6):

[#attached](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) can be used as follows.

```
$form['#attached']['js'][] = array(
  'data' => array(
    'xx_system' => array(
        'xx_code' => variable_get('xx_code', 'xx'),
        'xx_key' => variable_get('xx_key', 'xx'),
      ),
    ),
  'type' => 'setting',
);
```

With `drupal_add_js()`, you can use the following code.

```
 drupal_add_js(array('orgs' => $orgs), array('type' => 'setting'));
 drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/module_name.js');
```

In a JavaScript file, you can get the value of the variables as follows.

```
  Drupal.behaviors.module_name = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var cities = Drupal.settings.orgs.cities;// you will get the cities value here
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, Isn't that confined to the scope of a $form, for JS in every page shouldn't I use hook_page_alter with; $page['header']['#attached']['js']  etc. ?

Comment: besides I had mentioned above about files, my question relates to Drupal.settings, i.e. passing PHP variables and arrays through.

Comment: you can check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks again, but what I can't understand is why these examples always use $form, what about render arrays and adding js to every page?

Comment: To expand, when I've added js files using $form/#attached, they have only loaded within the $form array.

Comment: for adding js to every page u should use drupal_add_js(). There is no harm in using it.

Comment: I wrote a module and tried to follow best practice, but was told that drupal_add_js, and libraries_load (libraries API) was not allowed, and that I had to use #attached or it won't be put through. Harsh no?  BTW I'd  vote up your respone if I had enough points.

Comment: The second `drupal_add_js()` call is wrong: It should be similar to `drupal_add_js('misc/collapse.js');` which means the arguments passed to the function are just one.

Comment: is my updated answer right  @kiamlaluno?

Comment: It's exactly correct!